# encrypted SAML token

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I am using the php-saml toolkit https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml to implement an SSO in a web application. The authentication in itself works but when i check with an intercepting proxy https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload the saml token appears in clear (as xml, with the username along with all information passed for authentication). In the connector and the setting https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/settings_example.php i have set the certificate (in idp/x509cert)

I am not sure if the presence of the certFingerprint makes a difference, i tried with and without and the saml token is in clear in both cases.

Is it possible to have this saml response encrypted ? it is still signed so it cannot be changed but having this data in clear is still a problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed have the SAML response encrypted, and it will need to be setup by your Onelogin administrator for your application. Encrypting the Response ( or the Assertion ) is mitigated by using TLS as you're already encrypted at the transport layer, and *most* applications I see don't encrypt Response or Assertion, but it's available in Onelogin if needed.

Comment: Hi @niall_atlasidentity. Thank you for your reply. Could you be more specific about the configuration ? i have already set an X.509 certificate, a SAML signature algorithm and a sha fingerprint. I don't know where i could specify this.

Comment: Hi Igor. I'm presuming you have access to a Onelogin tenant to configure the application ? If so, Add an application. Search for "SAML Test". This will bring up a list of applications that allow for custom configuration of a SAML application. Select the one that says "Advanced". At the bottom of the Configuration tab, there's an option to encrypt the response and include the X.509 certificate that includes the public key for the application that makes the SAML request and expects an encrypted response

Comment: Thank you. indeed i had to change the connectors to the 'advanced' type to have the option available